# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker sometimes crashes the app

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, google-signin

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 app with Google login, which uses the

```
GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync
```

method. 90 % of the time, the authentication works, however, **occasionally**, the app just crashes on this line (I am logging right before it, so I am sure). I have the call wrapped inside try - catch, but that doesn't seem to work - exception is never caught.

I am also sure I am calling the method on a UI thread, I am using the DispatcherHelper from MVVMLight for that.

The fact that I am not able to reproduce the crash complicates this a lot, I have not experienced it with debugger attached, only in Release mode, on target device, run locally.

Do you guys have any ideas / clues / pointers? I know I'm not providing a lot of information, but I don't have any..

EDIT> So the error now happened with debugger attached - and the app just froze, last message in Ouput window was 
"WinRT information: Cannot get credential from Vault"
But that's normal behavior..

Comment: I'm experiencing the freeze-up behavior when debugging, but it happens every time. However, since the app freezes yet VS doesn't indicate a problem, I don't have any more information either. Do you have any suggestions what I could check to provide you with more info?

Comment: Does your app use background audio? I discovered I need to stop the background task before calling the authentication broker